# Making an action run in the background and not releasing it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an IBaction, once a user presses the IBaction a sound plays. The user is able to turn the sound on and off from pressing the button. Pressing the button once turns the sound on, pressing it again it turns the sound off.
It works perfectly in one view controller.
However this is my problem. I have 2 views and once the user plays the sound and wants to go to another view, the sound is still playing once on another view, but if they want to stop the sound, they will have to go back onto the view which contains the sound, but the problem is a new audio session is created meaning the existing sound cannot be turned off.
Does anyone know how to do it

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)twoSound:(id)sender; {
    if (ButtonAlReadyClicked == 1) 
    {
        ButtonAlReadyClicked = 2;

        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"z2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else if (ButtonAlReadyClicked == 2) 
    {
        ButtonAlReadyClicked = 1;

        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"z1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } 
    if (twoAudio && twoAudio.playing) {
        [twoAudio stop];
        [twoAudio release];
        twoAudio = nil;
        return;
    }    
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (twoAudio) [twoAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    twoAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    twoAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
    twoAudio.delegate = self;
    [twoAudio play];    


}

-(IBAction)goMain:(id)sender; {

      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate class that houses and keeps track of your audio. Add to that class a singleton and method to toggle the sound. This way it is only one class instance managing the music that is accessible to the entire app.